# Installing Angular with Ansible npm package

Tags: npm, ansible

I would like to use [Ansible's npm module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/npm_module.html) to install angular.
I here is the ansible task I have:

```
- name: Install npm rpm
  yum:
    name: "{{packages}}"
  vars:
    packages:
    - npm

- name: "Install Angular version {{ angular_version }}."
  npm:
    name: angular-cli
    version: "{{ angular_version }}"
    path: "{{ fe_deploy_dir }}/{{ fe_repo_basename }}"
```

I have tried setting `name` to `angular` and `angular/cli` and I get the error:

```
Linux 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv \"/usr/bin/node\" \"/usr/bin/npm\" \"install\" \"angular-cli@6.2.1\"
npm ERR! node v6.17.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found:********@6.2.1
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget 1.0.0-beta.22-1, 1.0.0-beta.20-4, 1.0.0-beta.20-3, 1.0.0-beta.20-2, 1.0.0-beta.20-1, 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile.4, 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile.3, 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile.2, 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile.1, 1.0.0-beta.2-mobile, 1.0.0-beta.19-3, 1.0.0-beta.12-1, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-4, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-3, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-2, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-1, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.7, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.6, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.5, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.4, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.3, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2, 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack, 1.0.0-beta.28.3, 1.0.0-beta.28.2, 1.0.0-beta.28, 1.0.0-beta.27, 1.0.0-beta.26, 1.0.0-beta.25.5, 1.0.0-beta.25.4, 1.0.0-beta.25.3, 1.0.0-beta.25.2, 1.0.0-beta.25, 1.0.0-beta.24, 1.0.0-beta.22, 1.0.0-beta.21, 1.0.0-beta.18, 1.0.0-beta.17, 1.0.0-beta.16, 1.0.0-beta.15, 1.0.0-beta.14, 1.0.0-beta.12, 1.0.0-beta.10, 1.0.0-beta.9, 1.0.0-beta.8, 1.0.0-beta.6, 1.0.0-beta.5, 1.0.0-beta.4, 1.0.0-beta.1, 1.0.0-beta.0, 0.1.0, 0.0.39, 0.0.37, 0.0.34, 0.0.33, 0.0.31, 0.0.30, 0.0.29, 0.0.28, 0.0.27, 0.0.26, 0.0.25, 0.0.24, 0.0.23, 0.0.22, 0.0.20, 0.0.19, 0.0.18, 0.0.17, 0.0.16, 0.0.15, 0.0.14, 0.0.13, 0.0.12, 0.0.11, 0.0.10, 0.0.9, 0.0.8, 0.0.7, 0.0.6, 0.0.5, 0.0.4, 0.0.3, 0.0.2, 0.0.1, 0.0.0
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /apps/fe-deploy/fe/npm-debug.log"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's no `angular@6.2.1` (that's AngularJS), `angular-cli@6.2.1` (that's the deprecated CLI package) or `angular/cli@6.2.1` (that doesn't exist at all). It's `@angular/cli@6.2.1`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli/v/6.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For install Angular over ansible I use this form:

```
- name: Install Angular.js
  npm:
    name: "@angular/cli@10"
    global: yes
    state: present
```

Pay attention that version after @ like part of package name. You can use other version like this "@angular/cli@10.0.2"
For look all available versions type into console

```
npm view @angular/cli versions
```